# Blackberry Network connection

Tags: blackberry, popfax-api

Trying to connect via Wi-Fi and I have an issue with the OS6 cd variable is null but it works on OS5

This is the url Strng: https://api3.popfax.com/index.php?service=Popfax;interface=wifi;interface=wifi

```
public ServiceConnectionBlackBerry(String s) throws IOException {
        ConnectionFactory cf = new ConnectionFactory();
        ConnectionDescriptor cd = cf.getConnection(s);
        if (cd!=null){
            connection = (HttpConnection) cd.getConnection();
        }else {
        System.out.println("Strng: "+s);}
      }
```

can someone help please.

Comment: Why are you appending the URL with interface=wifi?  I thought the point of ConnectionFactory was that it would choose which connection to use automatically?

Comment: I removed the connection information still it doesn't want to connect. I get null from the ConnectionFactory's method getconnection()

Answer (score 0):

When using `ConnectionFactory` you should not append any connection information to your URL.  So instead you should just pass `https://api3.popfax.com/index.php?service=Popfax` to your method.

Comment: I removed the connection information still it doesn't want to connect. I get null from the ConnectionFactory's method getconnection()

Comment: Well, the SDK docs indicate that `getConnection()` returns null if a connection cannot be established.  It sounds like your problem may be outside of your code -- a problem with your data connections?

Comment: Well using network diagnosis tool i get that wifi and all others fail on this device ... but very peculiar , the browser works perfectly ...

Comment: Perhaps you have a BIS connection available on your device?  The browser could most certainly use this, but unless you have been granted access to BIS for your application, your app would not be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

[Open a Wi-Fi HTTPS connection](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11938/Open_a_WiFi_HTTPS_connection_509042_11.jsp) may help you.

thanks

Comment: Still no help I try to use the Connector.open when the ConnctionFactory doesn't work and no luck

Comment: Are you use Httpsconnection or Httpconnection?