# Blackberry connection issue

Tags: blackberry

When connecting with a ConnectionFactory works on the simulator and doesn't work on a real device Torch 9800 works on Curve 9300 i ran the Network Diagnosis Tool on both showed an successful test with wifi on the curve but on the torch all tests fail, the strange part is that the browser works but both application and Network Diagnosis Tool fail. Can someone give me a clue ?

Added code :

```
ConnectionFactory cf = new ConnectionFactory();
         cf.setPreferredTransportTypes(new int[]{
                    TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_TCP_WIFI,
                    TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_TCP_CELLULAR,
                    TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_WAP,
                    TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_WAP2,
                    TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_MDS,
                    TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_BIS_B
                });
        ConnectionDescriptor cd = cf.getConnection(s);
        if (cd!=null){
            connection = (HttpConnection) cd.getConnection();
        }else {

            String appendix = getBlackBerryConnectionParams();
            System.out.println("Strng: "+appendix);
            connection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(s+appendix);
        }
```

Comment: Can you post the code you use to setup your connection, including the preferred and disallowed connection types?

Comment: Posted the code ... hope this is helpful

Comment: I would highly recommend combining / re-writing this question with your other question as they are really the same question, this is just slightly more refined now that some of the issue has been discovered (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502562/blackberry-network-connection)